# RestEasy Webservice Server Tutorial Baeldung not working Wildfly 20

Tags: rest, wildfly, resteasy

I am new to rest webservices. I wanted to test the tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-tutorial with wildfly 20. I created a maven project with the code I got from github. I built the project and sucessfully deployed it.
[image]

But if I try to make rest calls via postman (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8080/resteasy/movies/listmovies) I get "Error 404 not found" errors.
[image]

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>resteasy</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here is the MovieCrudService.java

```
 @Path("/movies")

public class MovieCrudService {

    private Map<String, Movie> inventory = new HashMap<String, Movie>();

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public Response index() {
        return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD").entity("").build();
    }
...
    
    @GET
    @Path("/listmovies")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public List<Movie> listMovies() {

        return inventory.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
```

Here is RestEasyServices.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestEasyServices extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public RestEasyServices() {
        singletons.add(new MovieCrudService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return super.getClasses();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return super.getProperties();
    }
}
```

Movie.java

```
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "movie", propOrder = { "imdbId", "title" })
public class Movie {

    protected String imdbId;
    protected String title;

    public Movie(String imdbId, String title) {
        this.imdbId = imdbId;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Movie() {}

    public String getImdbId() {
        return imdbId;
    }
...
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot, Nicole

Comment: You're making things far more difficult than they need to be.  You should be using the standard JAX-RS, not a RestEasy specific solution.  Take a look at my [JAX-RS example](https://github.com/stdunbar/jaxrs-sample) specifically written for Wildfly.

Comment: That looks good. But unfortunately I get a lot of errors. I created a maven project in eclipse with your code, I use Java 8 and Wildfly 20.0.1. So I think the errors come from project settings. Perhaps you have an eclipse project download for me?

Comment: That looks like a pretty standard Maven project. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. Also a +1 for not using RESTEasy specific settings. Using the JAX-RS or Jakarta RESTful Web Services specs is best. Another example would be https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/22.0.1.Final/helloworld-rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your servlet mapping is:

```
<param-value>/rest</param-value>
```

So the url you have to call should include "/rest" between the webapp context-path (/resteasy) and the resource path (/movies/listmovies):

http://127.0.0.1:8080/resteasy/rest/movies/listmovies